# Assigning multiple labels to product in GCP Vision

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, typeerror, google-cloud-vision

I'm using GCP Cloud Vision to catalogue products. After i've created a product, i have to update it to add labels to the product.

If i upload products via a CSV bulk import, labels can be formatted in the CSV as "color=black,style=formal" or "color=black,style=formal,style=mens". However when adding them to a specific product outside of the bulk import via the API, the example in the documentation asks for key and value as variables.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/update-resources

How can i assign multiple lables (the docs say it is supported) into the product via this API?

I've tried adding them as a list in the following format but i'm getting an error:

GCP Example:  `def update_product_labels(product_id, key, value):`

Attempt: `update_product_labels('axel-arigato-1',['category', 'colour'], ['shoes', 'black'])`

Error: `TypeError: ['category', 'colour'] has type list, but expected one of: bytes, unicode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sample code in the link you provided. It can be updated to create a list of `KeyValue()` and then pass that to create your `vision.Product()` object. See updated code below:

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2 as field_mask

def update_product_labels(
        project_id, location, product_id, key, value):
    """Update the product labels.
    Args:
        project_id: Id of the project.
        location: A compute region name.
        product_id: Id of the product.
        key: The key of the label.
        value: The value of the label.
    """
    client = vision.ProductSearchClient()

    # Get the name of the product.
    product_path = client.product_path(
        project=project_id, location=location, product=product_id)

    # Set product name, product label and product display name.
    # Multiple labels are also supported.

    key_len = len(key)
    value_len = len(value)
    key_value = []

    if key_len != value_len:
        print("Please enter equal indices for key and value")
    else:
        for n in range(key_len):
            key_value.append(vision.Product.KeyValue(key=key[n], value=value[n]))
        product = vision.Product(
                name=product_path,
                product_labels=key_value)

        # Updating only the product_labels field here.
        update_mask = field_mask.FieldMask(paths=['product_labels'])

        # This overwrites the product_labels.
        updated_product = client.update_product(
            product=product, update_mask=update_mask)

        # Display the updated product information.
        print('Product name: {}'.format(updated_product.name))
        print('Updated product labels: {}'.format(product.product_labels))

update_product_labels(
        project_id = "your-project-id",
        location = "us-east1", #used this location for testing
        product_id = "product_id0", #used this product_id for testing
        key = ['category', 'colour'],
        value = ['shoes', 'black'],
        )
```

Sample run:

[image]

Check the product if it was really applied. I sent a GET at the endpoint below:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
"https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/projects/your-project-id/locations/us-east1/products/product_id0"
```

Output when for get product:

[image]

NOTE: Updating the key value pair in this manner overwrites the previous data. So for example if you want to add a new key value pair, you should include the old data. When calling the function, your input should be `key = ['category', 'colour','new_key'], value = ['shoes', 'black', 'new_value']`.